# How do I sum an R dataframe into one cell?

Tags: r

I am trying to sum 2 dataframes named X and Y into one cell in a new dataframe named PL. The problem I am having is when I use this script :

```
df$PL <- sum(df$X + df$Y)
```

it propagates the entire PL column instead of just one cell.

How do I code it so it just fills one cell ?

Comment: What do you mean sum two data frames ? if `df` is a data frame, then `X` and `Y` are columns. In addition, `PL` is also a column, and not a cell. Can you post an example of what you're trying to do?

Comment: @RafaelC he means whole column PL is set to result

Comment: But what cell you want to be filled? Do you have index? Or what?

Comment: The irony here is that sum() produces one value whereas it appears that the OP wants as many "cells" (not an R term with any agreed-upon meaning) as there are "cells" in df$X). There are NOT "two dataframes but rather two R-"vectors". The OP's mind has been warped by Excel. Tools always warp out minds.

Answer (score 1):

The `sum()` function doesn't do vectorization. Just add them together. Also, you mean variables, i.e. columns, not data frames. `df` is, I assume, a data frame. You also mean rows, not cells, I would guess.

```
df$PL <- df$X + df$Y
```

If this is not what you want, then please share some example data along with what output you are looking for.